# sidewaystable will not plot side ways

Tags: tables, rotating

I am unable to get a `sidewaystable` to plot even with simple documents. I've copied this code directly and I can get it to plot as a normal table. It does not work when I change it to sideways. Does anyone have any suggestions? Here's the code I'm using for the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
Team              & P & W & D & L & F  & A & Pts \\
\hline
Manchester United & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 & 5 & 12  \\
Celtic            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 & 9 &  9  \\
Benfica           & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 & 8 &  7  \\
FC Copenhagen     & 6 & 2 & 1 & 2 &  5 & 8 &  7  \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{This should be a sideways table}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

This code plots the table horizontal and half off the page in the bottom corner. Why does it not create a vertical table?

Yep -- using pdflatex sorts the problem out.

Comment: Are you viewing the `.dvi`? Rotation is implemented as a source special, so if you are using the `dvips` route will not normally be visible until you convert to .`ps` format (or through to `.pdf`).